# Django Query too slow because of for()

Tags: django, performance, sqlite, database-design

Suppose context['cat'] is a list which can have several values ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] and 'category' field can also have several values:  ['X'] or ['X,Y'].

**This code** lets me obtain all the objects that I want. The **problem** is that I have 4 million records. When I tried this code on 100k records there was no delay, but with 4M records there is a 20secs delay.

```
paper_list = model1.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(category__icontains=x) for x in context['cat'])))
```

I have been told that the solution may be to use ManyToMany relations on the models but that is something that I don't know how to use even though I read the documentation [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Is there a way of making this possible without that structure? I wanted to use something like the LIKE expression on MySQL, but 'icontains' isn't giving me what I want unless I use a for(), which has delays with so many records.

In case it is of any help, this is the model I loaded all the records onto, and I don't have more records:

```
class model1(models.Model): 
   author= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   title= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   sum= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   key= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   iso= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   extra= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   url= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
   category= models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=199)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should learn about many-to-many relationships, as they are one of the basic relationships in relational databases. The `category` field is unnormalized, since it's storing multiple atomic values (each category) in one field.

Comment: I know this may not be the best approach there is. The issue here is that I also want to search for fields like the author and the extra (words) and some others, which are also just like category. To me it felt like putting ManyToMany relations on almost all fields isn't the best approach if it was possible to do it some other way.